# I get the error: file or assembly system system.data.sqlserverce not found

Tags: c#, windows-ce, windows-embedded-compact, compact-database

[Picture error from my device](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bPIdP.jpg)

On emulator it work but on my device it dosen't work.

I copy build file to my device and run. It right?

[file copy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uCCz3.png)

My device Infomation

- CE OS 5.2.29370
- .NET CF version 3.5.14269.0

Propreties DB I correct setup?

[Propreties DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m8oIQ.png)

Propreties Dataset I correct setup?

[Propreties Dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eR7SD.png)

I need show data on my device like a emulator device.

[Picture from emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B7WTM.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's not already, set `Copy Local` to `true` for that reference. That will copy the DLL to the output folder with your EXE when you build. You then deploy the DLL with your EXE.